# How to refresh multipage editor's page?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have created a plugin,Where I have a multi page editor with two pages. 
  Page1- Source Code Editor.
  Page2- For Manipulation.

My problem is if there is any compilation error in the code the second page must display another content like "Error".
 Otherwise it will show my manipulation form.
 For that I need to fill the composite with diffrent content each time the pageChanges. But it doesnt work.

How can achieve the scenario. While clicking the second page the content must be recreated or refreshed for the new content

```
  public void createPage1(){

    intializePage1Composite();

    updatePage1Content(this.page1Compostie);

    int index = addPage(this.page1Compostie);
    setPageText(index, "Service Behaviors ");
}
 public void updatePage1Content(Composite composite){

    boolean error=getPageStatus();


    if(!error){

        /**
         *Content of Normal Page
         */
    }

    /**
     * setting the page to error
     */
    else{
            /**
             *Content of Error Page
              */

        }
}


   protected void pageChange(int newPageIndex) {
    super.pageChange(newPageIndex);
    if (newPageIndex == 1) {


        updatePage1Content(this.page1Compostie);

        this.page1Compostie.redraw();


    }

}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Why do you create a new errorLabel control each time? Just create it at the beginning and call `setText` to change its contents.

Comment: @greg-449: Actually its a sample code there will be childs like table viewer ,lables, buttons  etc.., my problem is during page change if there is error it needs to show the error contents otherwisw normal content. IS it possible to remove all the contents inside a composite and refill it each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace all the children of a composite you first call `dispose()` on each existing child control. Next add the new controls. Finally call

```
composite.layout(true, true);
```

on the parent composite to force it to update the layout.

If you just want to switch between two sets of controls you can use the `GridData.exclude` flag and `Control.setVisible` to include/exclude controls. Again call `layout` at the end.